# Array_Filter/Array_Unique on an Array of Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I want to perform the following action on an array of arrays:

```
$fix = array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

foreach ($fix as &$f){
    $f = array_filter(array_unique($f));
}
```

Unfortunately, despite my efforts to pass each array by reference, I'm not getting filtered and uniquified results at the end of the process. Is there a simple way to get this done?  Or should I approach this problem in a different way?  I can just call the filtering etc on each array in turn, which works, but it seems like that can't be the DRY way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fix = array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

foreach ($fix as $k => $v){
    $fix[$k] = array_filter(array_unique($v));
}
```

---

Based on comments, a way to change the original variables:

```
$fix = compact($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
foreach ($fix as $k => $v){
    $fix[$k] = array_filter(array_unique($v));
}
extract($fix);
```

Comment: Because its using the default filter?

Comment: It's still not quite working for me for some reason (pre or post edit), though it seems like it should... maybe I'm being stupid?

Comment: When you say "not quite working" - what errors or wrong output are you getting?

Comment: @Amber: My apologies, I dashed away from work in a hurry last night and should have left a much less cryptic and non-specific comment before I did!  Basically $fix[0] now contains the correct results, but $array1 itself is unchanged; I think I was hoping to physically change the original array.  Maybe I'm mixed-up about what constitutes a desirable outcome though...

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, the problem there is that when you put `$array1` into `$fix`, there's no tie back to the original variable. Your options if you want to change the original variables are this - either keep an *array* of variable *names*, and use variable-variables to access the arrays (for DRY), or use an associative array mapping variable names to values (most easily created with `compact()`), and then use `extract()` to grab the new values out of them into the variables.